# How to get TouchableOpacity Text String

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to get number '1' of this TouchableOpacity?

```
numClick(){
    this.state.pressedNum = ?
}
render(){
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.numButton} onPress={()=>this.numClick()}>
            <Text style={styles.numString}>1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329240/react-native-onpress-being-called-automatically

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to extract the value from the actual Text component? If not you can just pass it to the function as an argument. By the way, you should not mutate state directly, use [setState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867038/what-the-difference-of-this-state-and-this-setstate-in-reactjs) instead.

```
numClick(num) {
    this.setState({
        pressedNum: num
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.numButton} onPress={()=>this.numClick(1)}>
            <Text style={styles.numString}>1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```