# react-native : onPress doesn't work

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, onpress

I work on an onPress event on react native. 
At a first time, I wrote that code :

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={(this.props.minimum==null||this.props.value-1>=this.props.minimum)
        ? this.props.onDecrement
        :console.log(this.props.texte+" : minimum atteint")}
    style={[buttonSpinner,buttonSpinnerLeft]}>
```

With that, my button works, but onPress is called automatically on each render() call.
I search and I found a solution here : [React Native onPress being called automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329240/react-native-onpress-being-called-automatically).

But now, if I don't have any automatic call... I don't have call when I press on my Touchable component.

I try some versions :

```
const p=this.props;
//some other code
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={()=>(p.minimum==null||p.value-1>=p.minimum)
        ? p.onDecrement
        :console.log(p.texte+" : minimum atteint")}
    style={[buttonSpinner,buttonSpinnerLeft]}>
```

--

```
const p=this.props;
// some other code
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={(p)=>(p.minimum==null||p.value-1>=p.minimum)
        ? p.onDecrement
        :console.log(p.texte+" : minimum atteint")}
    style={[buttonSpinner,buttonSpinnerLeft]}>
```

--

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={()=>(this.props.minimum==null||this.props.value-1>=this.props.minimum)
        ? this.props.onDecrement
        :console.log(this.props.texte+" : minimum atteint")}
    style={[buttonSpinner,buttonSpinnerLeft]}>
```

Without success...

Precision, I work on a separated component. This component is called in a main render like that :

```
<NumberSpinner
    onDecrement = {()=>this.onDecrement(elt.idCat,idElt)}
    onIncrement = {()=>this.onIncrement(elt.idCat,idElt)}
    minimum = {0}
    maximum = {null}
    texte = {elt.slug}
    value={elt.qteTxt}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move your logic in a function so use the `onPress` with a function call only

```
<TouchableOpacity
         onPress={this.onPress}
       >
   <Text> Touch Here </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and your function:

```
onPress = () => {
   //your logic here
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Or to be precise, I have the console.log who works but not the underfunction.

    onPressDecrement = () => 
        ((this.props.minimum==null||this.props.value-1>=this.props.minimum)
        ? this.props.onDecrement
        :console.log(this.props.texte+" : minimum atteint"));

I'm editing first post to precise the context.

Comment: So the onPress is working, the problem seems to be in your if statement.

Comment: if statement works correct on the first version (that who is called in each render)

Comment: It works ! With this code on function : 
onPressDecrement = () =>((this.props.minimum==null||this.props.value-1>=this.props.minimum)
        ? this.props.onDecrement()
        :console.log(this.props.texte+" : minimum atteint"));

Comment: o.. yes.. call the function :) I missed that too :p. Good job.

Comment: You need to import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` instead of importing it from `react-native-gesture-handler`. The version in `react-native-gesture-handler` is 100% broken. The version in `react-native` works.

The accepted answer does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` instead of importing it from `react-native-gesture-handler`. The version in `react-native-gesture-handler` is 100% broken. The version in `react-native` works.

The accepted answer does not solve this problem.