# Pass event handler as props to react-native custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a custom component called MyButton.js

```
  <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[styles.button, props.extraStyle]}
      onPress={props.onPress}
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{props.children}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

I pass the onPress handler for the button via props from parent SignUp.js

```
  <MyButton
    extraStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#03A9F4' }}
    onPress={this.signUpUser}
  >
    SIGN UP
  </MyButton>
```

Problem is that my signUpUser function (also in SignUp.js) needs to be passed 3 arguments

```
signUpUser = (userName, email, password) => {
    try {
      //handle password<6 and bad email format etc pls!!!!
      Firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => {
          console.log('User created in firebase', user);
          //update FB with userNameNode......and default values for profile
          Firebase.database()
            .ref('profiles/users/' + user.user.uid)
            .set({
              active: false,
              emailAddress: email,
              userName: userName,
              userId: user.user.uid,
              ................
              ................
```

If I change the onPress prop of MyButton compoment as below to pass args....I get error in that it logs user in before theyve even pressed the button

```
<MyButton
    extraStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#03A9F4' }}
    onPress={this.signUpUser(
      this.state.userName,
      this.state.email,
      this.state.password,
    )}
  >
    SIGN UP
  </MyButton>
```

Can someone please help?  Ive been up all night with this lol

Comment: have you tried using an anonymous function ?
`onPress={() => this.callYourFunction(...)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

> onPress={this.signUpUser(blabla)}

to

> onPress={() => this.signUpUser(blabla)}

There is a similar post here,
[React Native onPress being called automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329240/react-native-onpress-being-called-automatically)

Comment: Hahaha, no problem.